# Argue that real matrices which are orthogonal form a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Argue that real matrices which are orthogonal form a group with matrix multiplication as the composition.

I know that a group have to satisfy $3$ axioms.

$1.$ $$(a \circ b) \circ c = a \circ (b \circ c)$$
$2.$ $$e \circ a = a \circ e =a$$ where $e$ is identity element

$3.$ $$a \circ a^{-1}=a^{-1} \circ a= e$$

But how should I begin? And is it a finite group?

Comment: 1. is clear, because matrix multiplication is associative. 2. is clear with $e=I_n$, and 3. is also clear because $A^{-1}$ is again orthogonal if $A$ is.

Comment: The first property follows from the associativity of matrix multiplication. Similarly for the second property with the identity matrix. What you really need to check, which you haven't listed, is that orthogonal matrices are closed under matrix multiplication. To show this, consider two orthogonal matrixes $A$ and $B$ and show that $AB$ is also an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is clear from the definition of multiplication between matrices;
2. Take $e = I_n$ the identity matrix (which is orthogonal);
3. If $A$ is orthogonal, then $A \cdot A^T = I$, therefore $A^{-1} = A^T$. Meaning to say that every element in the set (usually denoted by $\mathcal O(n)$) has an inverse.

To conclude you need to show that the set of all orthogonal matrices is closed under multiplication. Well, if $A,B$ are orthogonal then $$(A\cdot B)\cdot(A\cdot B)^T = (A \cdot B) (B^T\cdot A^T) = A \cdot (B\cdot B^T) \cdot A^T = \ldots$$

I believe you can take it from here

Comment: Is it a finite group then?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments the key fact here is to prove that the set of orthogonal matrices is closed under multiplication. So, let $A$, $B$ orthogonal matrices, i.e. (by definition) such that $AA^T=I$ and $BB^T=I$. we have:

$$
AB(AB)^T=ABB^TA^T=AA^T=I
$$
so also $AB$ is orthogonal.

Now the other properties are obvious:

1) come from distributivity of matrix multiplication.

2) is true because the identity matrix is orthogonal

3) is proved since  $AA^T=I \Rightarrow A^TA=I \Rightarrow A^-1=A^T$ .

Comment: So, let A,B ...... I edit !

Comment: I suppose it is just a typo

Comment: "1) come from distributivity" - rather, associativity